# Could someone explain this recursive function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

I have made a recursive function for finding the number in a position of the fibonacci sequence. The user enters a number (the term) and it runs the number through the function to find the number.

```
def fib(number):

if number == 0:
    return 0
if number == 1:
    return 1
else:
    number = fib(number - 1) + fib(number - 2)
    return number

user = int(input("Enter a position in the fibonacci sequence: "))

print fib(user)
```

If I input '4', could somebody explain how this number would be run through my recursive function?

thank you.

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: So... you don't understand your own program?

Comment: Plus you have formatting problems.

Comment: For understanding recursion you have to understand how function works , for understanding functions you have to understand how memory (stack , heap) works , then you will able to understand recursion.

Read this post :

http://cryptroix.com/2016/10/10/understanding-multiple-recursion/

Comment: Four is NOT a fib sequence: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21  - so garbage in- garbage out applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the `if` statements:

```
fib(0) = 0

fib(1) = 1

fib(2) = fib(2-1) + fib(2-2)
       = fib(1)   + fib(0)
       = 1        + 0
       = 1

fib(3) = fib(3-1)            + fib(3-2)
       = fib(2)              + fib(1)
       = fib(2-1) + fib(2-2) + 1
       = fib(1)   + fib(0)   + 1
       = 1        + 0        + 1
       = 2

fib(4) = fib(4-1)                       + fib(4-2)
       = fib(3)                         + fib(2)
       = fib(3-1)            + fib(3-2) + fib(2-1) + fib(2-2)
       = fib(2)              + fib(1)   + fib(1)   + fib(0)
       = fib(2-1) + fib(2-2) + 1        + 1        + 0
       = fib(1)   + fib(0)   + 1        + 1        + 0
       = 1        + 0        + 1        + 1        + 0
       = 3
```